# distributed storage solutions

Tags: distributed-filesystems, shared-storage, distributed-computing, cluster-shared-volumes

I've got some desktop PCs available in my company since the last user hardware renewal and I would like to re-use them for a demo plaform.  They are powerfull enought to emulate a few servers.  I guess I could do some virtualization farm, however I've got no available NAS nor SAN for them to connect to.  And I need a shared storage among the nodes to provide hot-migration.

So here's my question, what are the options to build a shared storage among approx. 10 nodes?  Should I consider GlusterFS?  Are Ceph and also HDFS to be considered for that purpose and why?  Are there other tricks out there that have been tested, possibly with ZFS?  I could even consider building a RAID among the nodes myself using software raid and iSCSI.

The objective is to build congruent systems with both, virtualization AND storage on the nodes.  So if loose one node, both failover capabilities come in action.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for testing purposes and virtualization, you could use Hyper-V. There is no need for a storage, you can use SMB 3.0 shares as shared storage. Take a look at this [Technet Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134187.aspx). Maybe this already fits your needs.